# How to select element based on it's value in select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I need to select a state based on the value between `<option>HERE</option> not <option value="HERE"></option>`

I was trying to go with something like this:

```
$('[name="region_id"]').select2("val", 'PA'); 

<select name="region_id">
 <option value="1">NJ</option>
 <option value="2">PA</option>
 <option value="3">DE</option>
</select>
```

but it doesn't work as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: try adding input to your jquery selector $( 'input[name="region_id"]')

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var search = 'PA';

var value = $('[name="region_id"] option:contains("' + search + '")').val();
$('[name="region_id"]').select2("val", value);
```

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mp6aY/)

More: [Select2 - Programmatic Access](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#programmatic)

Comment: It select it successfully but when the form gets submitted the region_id is empty. It look like it happens because the id parameter is not submitted so $('[name="region_id"]').select2("data", {text: 'PA'}); creates another option with no value.

Comment: @user1029829 Ah, good pickup - I've updated my solution to get the correct `option` element first, and then get the value from that.